# Condition property failure in WIX failing entire MSI job

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using WIX to create MSI installers for C# services. The MSI does 3 jobs :

a) Copy solution file from bin to a particular location.

b) Create a folder where the service writes it's logs.

c) install the service on the machine if it previously does not exist.

The want these to execute in the similar order. But, when the condition to check if the service is installed fails the previous step does not seem to be executing, i.e, copying and creating steps fail too.

Here is the snippet of the code.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">      
  <!--Creating folder hierarchy for storing project solution files;  reference defined in fragments-->
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles"/>

  <!--Creating folder hierarchy for storing logs; reference defined in fragments-->
  <Directory Id="LOGS" Name="Logs"/>
</Directory>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <LaunchConditions After='AppSearch' />
  <Custom Action='CMDInstallService' Before='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

```
<Property Id="MYSERVICE">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SERVICE_CHECK" Root="HKLM" Name="Install" Type="raw"
                      Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Service"/>
</Property>

<Condition Message="Service is already installed on your system">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR MYSERVICE]]>
</Condition>

<CustomAction
  Id='CMDInstallService' Directory='PROJECT_INSTALL' Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no'
  ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /K &quot;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe Service.exe&quot;'
  Return ='check'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work because the files and folder are not committed before `InstallFinalize`. To install a service, you should use the following command:

```
<Component Id="Component_WinService" Directory="Directory_WindowsService" Guid="*">

    <File Id="File_WindowsService" KeyPath="yes"
                Source="WindowsService.exe" />

    <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstall_WindowsService"
                                    Type="ownProcess"
                                    Vital="yes"
                                    Name="My Windows service"
                                    Description="Windows service."
                                    Start="auto"
                                    Account="LocalSystem"
                                    ErrorControl="ignore"
                                    Interactive="no" 
                                    />

    <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl_WindowsService"
                                    Start="install"
                                    Stop="both"
                                    Remove="uninstall"
                                    Name="My Windows Service" 
                                    Wait="no"
                                    />

</Component>
```

Comment: I removed the custom action. The service installer is not currently working. It throws the error, "Service 'myService' (myService) failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."

 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\adodb\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\adodb.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

Comment: Is your installation running elevated? Did you change the `Account` of `ServiceInstall`? These are the common questions. For more information on the real cause, you must run the installation from an elevated command prompt using the following: `msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.txt` and then search the log for any error related to service start.

Comment: marlos, I am running on InstallPrivileges="elevated". log file does not have any extra errors. And I can install the service manually using the Installutill,.exe

Comment: the service installation works fine now. There were previous copies of my service. Once I cleaned them, it started running by itself.